# Error connecting to service hosted in service fabric cluser in azure from my browser

Tags: configuration, azure-service-fabric

1. Authored web api service hosted in service fabric.
2. Navigated successfully to the service endpoint (on my machine) with
   following url: http://localhost:2500/days/v1.0/ (i.e. I can see the response).
3. Next created a UNSECURED service fabric cluster in the azure.
4. Published my local fabric app to azure through visual studio.
5. Successfully navigated to fabric explorer in the azure with url: http://xyz1234fake.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer
6. When looked at my service instance in explorer, it shows the url as     http://10.0.0.5:2500/days/v1.0/
7. In the browser, replaced the above local azure ip address with azure service cluster. For example: changed the url from http://10.0.0.5:2500/days/v1.0/ to http://xyz1234fake.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:2500/days/v1.0/
8. Was not able to navigate to above url.

What am I doing wrong? Where should I look for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

19000 and 19080 are reserved for communication to the cluster itself (19080 for the Explorer). You need to set up a new load balancer rule/probe for your application. You can do this in the Azure Portal under "Load Balancer".

Answer (score 0):

You need to open that port on the cluster. 19080 is open by default for non SSL connections, so if you just switch to that it'd work. Be careful not to use a port reserved for your services.

[This is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070891/err-connection-timed-out-when-trying-to-access-a-service-fabric-service/38100602#38100602)

Comment: When I created the cluster, it created load balancing rule called LBHttpRule that mapped public side port 19080 to back end port 19080. I am not sure what you mean by if you switch to 19080 port.Can you please elaborate? Also I was able to connect by creating a new LB rule that maps port 9000 to back end port 2500 and by changing the url to: http://xyz1234fake.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:9000/days/v1.0/

Comment: You did exactly what I meant, except with your own LB probe.